# Dynamics CRM SystemUser IsDisabled Field Unavailable for Mapping in SSIS

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to migrate user data from SQL to dynamics CRM using an SSIS package. There are some inactive users that must be migrated and I'd like to programmatically disable them in CRM. However, in my CRM destination source in my SSIS package, the IsDisabled field (an option set) in the SystemUser entity is not available for mapping. Is there any way to get the IsDisabled field to show up so I can programmatically disable certain users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a user inside CRM already disabled, you need to create first and after disable using a SetStateRequest. Check this link:

[Sample: Disable a User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602914.aspx)

Comment: Ah well that's a bummer. Thanks for the link and quick response!

Comment: if you want an easy way to disable a user you can create a custom field inside the systemuser entity (for example new_todisable) and attach a plugin on Create message with the logic to check this field and disable the record.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a link to a good tutorial for creating & attaching CRM plugins to the SystemUser OnCreate? I'm fairly new to this stuff :)

Comment: check this link

[http://happycrm.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-create-simple-plugin-in-ms-crm.html](http://happycrm.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-create-simple-plugin-in-ms-crm.html).

Maybe you can also create a workflow, if it's more easy for you.